# Chrome opens to the correct site and then immediately closes while using selenium

Tags: python, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am just getting into Webscraping and for some reason when I run my python code chrome pops up but to the correct page and then closes and shuts down after about 2 seconds. I was just wondering what i'm doing wrong or anything i can do differently for it to stay open.

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.fotmob.com/'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)

browser.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[2]/div[1]/section/section/div[2]/div[1]/a[1]')
```

Comment: when script ends its work then it may automaticaly remove all running (sub)programs. It may need to run some code which keeps Python code running - ie. `input()` which waits for ENTER pressed by user. Or you may run `while True` loop at the end. Later you may add some extra code in loop to create `REPL` (`Read Execute Print Loop`).